# Kivy - Black screen error in label

Tags: python, label, kivy, display

I created a label in kivy which contains a lot of information. It comes under a scrollview widget hence becoming a scrollable label. But since it has a lot of information it turns black and doesn't display anything. Also it has text with font roboto and size 30. I believe this is causing the error. Also it seems to not raise any error.

Could anyone help me overcome this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [ScrollLabel](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.scrolllabel) instead, it was created specifically to avoid this problem.